# Embed openVpn client in my own android application

Tags: java, android, client, openvpn

I want to provide the openVpn client config with my app, so the client will just connect the android system.I ve checked the ics-openVpn project in github, but i don t know how to start

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

See the doc/README in that repository for starting. Also make sure that you understand the implications of the GPL.